# How to use namespace programmed extension in Yii 1

Tags: php, yii, namespaces, yii-extensions

I need to use https://github.com/maxmind/GeoIP2-php extension in Yii version 1 project (i.e. without namespace concept project).

Tried: `$reader = new \GeoIp2\Database\Reader('/path/to/GeoIP2-City.mmdb');`

The main.php has following code:

```
'import' => array(
    'common.extensions.*',
   )
```

Also common/extensions folder has the above extension under 'GeoIP2' folder.

But no luck. The error is:

> Fatal error: Class 'GeoIp2\Database\Reader' not found in
>   .....Controller.php on line ..

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Got it working by doing the following:

In *main.php*, I added the following lines:

```
Yii::setPathOfAlias('GeoIp2',Yii::getPathOfAlias('common.extensions.GeoIp2.src'));
```

In *controller-action*, I modified the line:

`$reader = new GeoIp2\Database\Reader('/path/to/GeoIP2-City.mmdb');`

If anyone knows any other way, please let us know.

It may help later.